# Quick Sort - comparison/exchange counters

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures

Good morning. I made a program that implements several different sorting methods on an array of 2000 items and produces the number of comparisons & exchanges for each sorting method.

When I choose the quicksort method, it gives me this output:

---

"Number of exchanges: 1

Number of comparisons: 2

Number of exchanges: 1

Number of comparisons: 2

Number of exchanges: 1

Number of comparisons: 6

Number of exchanges: 1

Number of comparisons: 2

Number of exchanges: 1

...

...

Quick sorting completed.

---

This is an example using bubble sort of what I want the output to be:

---

Number of comparisons: 1999

Number of exchanges: 0

Bubble sorting completed.

---

I know that I need to move the comparison & exchange counters but I can't figure out where to move them in order to receive the desired results.

Can anybody please help?

I truly appreciate it! It's driving me bananas.

Here is my code for Quick Sort:

```
    // QUICK SORT
public static void quickSort(AnyType[] array, int low, int high)
{
    int i = low, j = high, comparisons = 0, exchanges = 0;
    AnyType temp, pivot = array[(low + high)/2];

    while (i <= j)
    {
        while(array[i].isLessThan(pivot))
        {
            i++;
            comparisons++;
        }
        while(array[j].isBetterThan(pivot))
        {
            j--;
            comparisons++;
        }
        if (i <= j) {
            temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[j];
            array[j] = temp;
            i++;
            j--;
            exchanges++;
        }
    }

    if (low < j) 
    {
        quickSort(array, low, j);
    }
    if (i < high) 
    {
        quickSort(array, i, high);
    }

    System.out.println("Number of comparisons: "+ comparisons);
    System.out.println("Number of exchanges: "+ exchanges);
}
```

Comment: Please show the array (as much as needed to understand how it's structured). What are exchanges and comparisons? Tip: Sometimes it can help breaking the loops up into separate loops (and not "loops in loops" as the code is currently structured).

Comment: The reason you're getting multiple lines of output is because the last line of the `quickSort` method outputs to the console, and you are calling the method multiple times (recursively). Perhaps you could change the method so that it returns the metadata you want?

Comment: how would i do that?

Answer (score 0):

You're calling quickSort() on itself recursively. For every iteration it will execute the println code when it returns from the subsequent call. You need to make sure that the printing code only executes on the outermost (first) iteration of the method.